# Java 8 comparison of 2 different lists

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I need a help on iterating and comparing 2 different list using java 8. If one of the attribute matches then i need to set the values of one list into another. An employee can have multiple projects.
EmployeeDto{   --List
Name
Id
Number
ProjectList }

I have  a List projectList
ProjectDto
{
Id,
ProjectName....}

I want to compare employeeList and projectList. Check if Id matches from both list then set
employeeDto.setProjectList(projectList)

```
         List<ProjectDto> newList = new Arraylist<>();
         for(EmployeeDto emp: employeeList) {
         for(ProjectDto project: ProjectList){

           if(project.getId().equals(emp.getId())){

               newList.add(project);

             }
             emp.setProjectList(newList));
           }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: for(EmployeeDto dto: employeeList){  projectList.stream().filter(x--> x.getid.equals(dto.getId().map(dto.setProjectList(x)))). Since this a list i am not sure on .map condition. I know this is wrong. I want to add project to list and then set it to employeedto

Answer (score 0):

```
employeeList.forEach(employee -> {
  employee.setProjectList(projectList.stream()
    .filter(project -> Objects.equals(employee.getId(), project.getId()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
});
```

That is one possible way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do `O(n^2)` work. You can group the projects by emp ID first.

```
Map<String, List<ProjectDto>> grouped = projects.stream().collect(groupingBy(ProjectDto::getId, toList()));
```

Then simply iterate through your employees and set the respective projectList for each one.

```
employees.forEach(emp -> emp.setProjectList(grouped.getOrDefault(emp.getId(), new ArrayList<>())));
```